# Cannot drop a database in Azure Data Studio, because it's currently in use

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

I cannot drop custom databases in Azure Data Studio, because they are currently in use.

I've been looking for various ways to close the `zap` database, but I cannot find any in the UI.

Only by restarting Azure Data Studio, is the `zap` database in an "Auto Closed" state, which lets me drop it using:

`drop database zap;`

How do I close a connection to a database without restarting Azure Data Studio?

**Open:**
[image]

**Auto-closed:**
[image]

Comment: Try `USE master;ALTER DATABASE zap SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;DROP DATABASE zap;`

Comment: that didnt work

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Someone else is connected, so you need to set it to `SINGLE_USER`. This will terminate any existing connections, so that the database can be dropped.

```
USE master;
GO

ALTER DATABASE zap SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
DROP DATABASE zap;
GO
```

Comment: If someone could advise why this is unuseful, that would be great.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what your query does? Also how can someone else be connected, when I'm the only user?

Comment: I explain that in the opening statement, @Shuzheng : *"This will terminate any existing connections, so that the database can be dropped."* It *might* be an Agent job, another query window, etc. Looking at your first image, looks like you have the management page open for the database `zap`; that will be at least one (other) connection there.

Comment: Ohh, so each tab (page) makes a separate connection to the database? I thought that connections only exist for the DBMS (SqlServer), and not to the individual databases - am I wrong? Also, why is `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` necessary in the query?

Comment: No, if you have 7 "tabs" open, and are connected to the server in each of them, you have 7 connections. Those Connections with be what ever database you have in "use" on those tabs (and what database you are connected to is connection dependant).

Comment: so although, the connections are from the same user (my user in this case), they are seen as different connections? Why is `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` needed?

Comment: Yes, @Shuzheng ,you don't utilise the same connection across multiple tabs; each one has it's own connection. `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` does what it says on the tin; it immediately rollbacks back any transactions. Without that, you would have to wait for any connections to close and commit their transactions (so you'd be inn the same boat as you were before and the `SET SINGLE_USER` command would likely time-out).

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following:

```
use master;
go
ALTER DATABASE zap SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
Go
```

then drop database.

There is no need to find session which is connected to your database. it can be as simple as an object explorer open in another window. kill the session with the command above and then drop the database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/set-a-database-to-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I was writting my answer at the same time as yours. There is no need for that downvote... If I put that answer there 30 minutes later, yes, but my answer actually explains the code so took longer to write; yours does not. (Yes, I know the downvote was yours, as your reputation lowered by one after a refresh).

Comment: Thanks! Is it normal that you need to use such queries to drop a database? Also, can you explain what your query does?

Comment: basically, if other users are connected to the database at the time that you set the database to single-user mode, their connections to the database will be closed without warning. this is as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/set-a-database-to-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: so, if any sessions/users are connected to the database, they will be 'zapped' off.

Comment: Thanks. Do multiple connections from the same user also count as separate connections, so that I cannot drop the database, if I have several connections? Could you explain why `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` is necessary?

Comment: basically, rollback immediate will rollback all pending transactions immediately  and then alter the database